# Is there a way to get information about other apps notifications in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-developer-api

I tried to search for a way to get other apps notifications in Java or kotlin, but I couldn't find anything. For example, let's suppose Facebook sent you a push notification, is there any way I can use to get informations (e.g. content, or images that appear on the push notification) about this Facebook notification on the local device using java or kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a way to do this, but I've read that there is a `NotificationListenerService` that you can use to get information from active notifications. I haven't used it myself. But seems like a good point to start. There is a particular method you may want to check: `onNotificationPosted`

I'll link documentation.

[NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService#onNotificationPosted(android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification,%20android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService.RankingMap))

Hope it's of any help.

Comment: Thank you, I am not a native Android developer, so I was even struggling to know where to start searching, your answer was very helpful.